providing specification yaml as string to swagger ui bundle
we have a product which does not expose the swagger.json file via a uri.
The platform api however does provide an endpoint that returns it as a string in the response like below
{
"assetId": ,
"assetName": ,
"specification": "the specification yaml here"
}

I want to host this specification in a swagger-ui on our frontend application.
However from the documentation, the field spec can have a javascript object whereeas the other fields like configUrl, url and urls all expect a URI
Is there any way I can directly use the string specs as an input to to SwaggerUIBundle
